# Error when i need a location android

Tags: android, gps, location, runtime-error

I have a problem. In my app i need current location from a user. It works fine when we have a location(when i get a location usig method locationManager.getLastKnownLocation), but when i restart my phone and location disappear (cash is empty i presume) i get this log and force close app button. I click on a button, my app restarts and then it works fine...
I now that a problem is with location that return null...
This is the log:

```
08-25 10:02:55.000: ERROR/GPS(2006): gen_timer_add_locked
08-25 10:02:55.449: DEBUG/libgps(2006): onUnsol: cmd 0x04 plen 57
08-25 10:02:55.449: DEBUG/libgps(2006): oem_unsol_gps_measurement: num_sv 0
08-25 10:02:55.449: DEBUG/libgps(2006): oem_unsol_gps_measurement: used_in_fix_mask 00000000 
08-25 10:02:55.503: DEBUG/libgps(2006): request_location_fix_callback: session status 1
08-25 10:02:55.503: DEBUG/libgps(2006): request_location_fix_callback: GPS session is ongoing.
08-25 10:02:55.503: ERROR/GPS(2006): gen_timer_add_locked
08-25 10:02:56.006: DEBUG/libgps(2006): request_location_fix_callback: session status 1
08-25 10:02:56.006: DEBUG/libgps(2006): request_location_fix_callback: GPS session is ongoing.
08-25 10:02:56.006: ERROR/GPS(2006): gen_timer_add_locked
08-25 10:02:56.449: DEBUG/libgps(2006): onUnsol: cmd 0x04 plen 57
08-25 10:02:56.449: DEBUG/libgps(2006): oem_unsol_gps_measurement: num_sv 0
08-25 10:02:56.449: DEBUG/libgps(2006): oem_unsol_gps_measurement: used_in_fix_mask 00000000 
08-25 10:02:56.505: DEBUG/libgps(2006): request_location_fix_callback: session status 1
08-25 10:02:56.505: DEBUG/libgps(2006): request_location_fix_callback: GPS session is ongoing.
08-25 10:02:56.505: ERROR/GPS(2006): gen_timer_add_locked
08-25 10:02:57.009: DEBUG/libgps(2006): request_location_fix_callback: session status 1
08-25 10:02:57.009: DEBUG/libgps(2006): request_location_fix_callback: GPS session is ongoing.
08-25 10:02:57.009: ERROR/GPS(2006): gen_timer_add_locked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I created AlertDialog with no buttons and started requestLocationUpdates. In locationListener, when location changed i canceled AlertDialog and that solved my problem :D
THANKS jainal and Torsten....

Answer (score 0):

when you restart your phone then all the non-persistent data will be cleared like variable.If you want to save your location then you should use database/sharedPreferences.
Also,you can get `null` location.So you should keep checking to handle.

### Edited

You can use Timer class.

Try like this:

```
 Timer timer1;
  LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
  timer1=new Timer();
  timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
```

Following code will be executed after 20 sec.

```
class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             timer1.cancel();
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListener)
             Location loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. My location is null. I want to know how i can get my location or how i can give some time to requestLocationUpdates to give me some location??? I'm new in android :)

Comment: Thanks man!!! I will try that and i'll be back with the answer of what happened...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [A Deep Dive Into Location](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html)  to know pretty much all about how to get a location.